# Create method for a dynamic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm sorry if there any similar question like this, but I confuse on how to solve my problem so I can keep my code DRY.

I need to create a **Task List** so the user can see what transactions that haven't been post.

my `application_controller.rb` i would like create something like:

**(A)**

```
def to_do_list(var)
  @var.tableize = var.camelize.where(:status => 0).order("id desc")
end
```

or

**(B)**

```
def to_do_list(var, model_to_do)
  var = model_to_do.where(:status => 0).order("id desc")
end
```

while my `home_controller.rb` i want to call like:

**(A)**

```
to_do_list(purchase_order_header)
to_do_list(purchase_invoice_header)
etc
```

or

**(B)**

```
to_do_list(@purchase_order_headers, PurchaseOrderHeader)
to_do_list(@purchase_invoice_headers, PurchaseInvoiceHeader)
etc
```

I confuse on how to do that, and send those parameter and set on my method, thanks for any help :D

ps. I prefer option **(A)** if can provide it. Thanks.

Comment: I also done trying for option **(A)** like `"@#{var}".tableize = "#{var}".camelize.....`

But still return error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve but please try it out

```
to_do_list('purchase_order_header')
to_do_list('purchase_invoice_header')

def to_do_list(model)
  instance_variable_set "@#{model}", model.camelize.constantize.where(:status => 0).order("id desc")
end
```

after calling `to_do_list`, you should have instance variables called `@purchase_order_header` and `@purchase_invoice_header`